# Kommaregeln: Ist das ein Haupt- oder Nebensatz mit deshalb?

Tags: comma

Ich habe eine Deutschprüfung gemacht und bin durchgefallen und gehe jetzt meine Antworten durch.

Bei einer der Musterantworten habe ich jedoch Zweifel an ihrer Richtigkeit. Es geht um den folgenden Satz. (Der ganze Text steht weiter unten):

> Natürlich will die Branche Geräte verkaufen, [ ] deshalb sollte man solche Warnungen mit Vorsicht geniessen, [ ] vor allem in Inseraten.

In die eckigen Klammern musste ich die Kommaregel reinschreiben.

Nun denke ich, dass das erste Komma vor dem *»deshalb«* zwei Hauptsätze trennt. Warum? Weil ich das Komma durch einen Punkt ersetzen kann. Also würde ich Regel [2] wählen. Aber, wie aus dem Screenshot ersichtlich ist, ist die richtige Antwort 1. Und ich verstehe nicht, warum.

Vielen Dank für eure Hilfe.

---

So sah das Feedback auf meine Antwort aus:

> Die Antwort ist teilweise richtig.
>
> Sie haben 4 richtig ausgewählt.
> Die richtige Antwort lautet:
>
> **Nennen Sie die Kommaregel**
>
> **Obligatorische Kommas - eine Auswahl von Regeln**
>
> 1. Komma zwischen verschiedenrangigen Teilsätzen (Haupsatz-Nebensatz oder Partizip- und Infinitivsatz)
> 2. Komma zwischen gleichrangigen Wortgruppen oder Wörtern und Teilsätzen (Aufzählung; Hauptsatz-Hauptsatz; Nebensatz-Nebensatz)
> 3. Komma vor entgegenstellenden Konjunktionen im Teilsatz (aber, jedoch, sondern,...)
> 4. Komma bei Appositionen, Anreden und Ausrufen und vor nachgestellten Angaben (also, besonders, und zwar, vor altem, zum Beispiel ...)
>
> Natürlich will die Branche Geräte verkaufen, [1] deshalb sollte man solche Warnungen mit Vorsicht genießen, [4] vor allem in Inseraten. Aber an der Aussage ist etwas dran. Hören, [4] einer der wichtigsten Sinne, [4] ist mehr als nur blosse Wahrnehmung akustischer Wellen. Diese Sinnesreize müssen im Gehirn auch verarbeitet werc en: Wir lernen etwa, [1] Sprachsignale von Hintergrundgeräuschen zu trennen. Unser Gehirn besitzt eine gewisse Plastizität: Es widmet die Nervenzellen ständig um, [1] wenn also nur noch wenige Signale aus dem Gehör eintreffen, [1] dann kann es die entsprechenden Hirnareale anderen Sinnen, [4] dem Sehen, [2] dem Riechen, [2] dem Fühlen oder dem Schmecken, [4] zur Verfügung stellen. Vor drei Jahren haben Forscher der Universität von Colorado in den USA nachgewiesen, [1] dass schon bei Menschen mit einer leichten Altersschwerhörigkeit der Sehsinn beginnt, [1] Teile des auditiven Cortex zu beschlagnahmen (Quelle: Hearing
> Research), [1] die so genannte Auditive Deprivation.

Answer (score 2):

Es ist richtig, dass hier das Komma durch einen Punkt ersetzt werden kann. Der Grund dafür ist, dass ein Satz, der mit der Konjunktion *»deshalb«* beginnt, ein Hauptsatz ist. Das finite Verb (hier eine Form des Modalverbs *»sollen«*) steht direkt hinter der Konjunktion, also an Position 2, was typisch für Hauptsätze ist. In einem Nebensatz müsste dieses Verb ganz am Ende stehen.

- Hauptsätze (finites Verb an Position 2)

  > Man **sollte** solche Warnungen mit Vorsicht geniessen.
  > Solche Warnungen **sollte** man mit Vorsicht geniessen.
  > Deshalb **sollte** man solche Warnungen mit Vorsicht geniessen.
- Nebensätze (finites Verb am Ende)

  > Das ist wichtig, da man solche Warnungen mit Vorsicht geniessen **sollte**.
  > Es ist wichtig zu wissen, dass man solche Warnungen mit Vorsicht geniessen **sollte**.
  > Darauf muss man immer achten, obwohl man solche Warnungen mit Vorsicht geniessen **sollte**.

### Aber:

Die Wörter *»deshalb«, »deswegen«* und *»daher«* sind trotzdem Subjunktionen (unterordnende Konjunktionen), sie ziehn eine *konsekutive Satzverbindung* nach sich. Eine konsekutive Satzverbindung verbindet zwei Sätze, wovon der erste eine Ursache und der zweite eine Konsequenz dieser Ursache ist.

| Ursache | Konsequenz | verbundener Satz |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Es regnet. | Ich bleibe daheim. | Es regnet, **daher** bleibe ich daheim. |
| Georg hat Hunger. | Er isst etwas. | Georg hat Hunger, **deswegen** isst er etwas. |
| Natürlich will die Branche Geräte verkaufen. | Man sollte solche Warnungen mit Vorsicht geniessen. | Natürlich will die Branche Geräte verkaufen, **deshalb** sollte man solche Warnungen mit Vorsicht geniessen. |

Der Satz, der die Konsequenz beinhaltet, ist zwar grammatikalisch ein Hauptsatz, hängt aber semantisch trotzdem von einem übergeordneten Satz ab. Daher sind die beiden Teilsätze nicht gleichrangig.

Answer (score 2):

> Natürlich will die Branche Geräte verkaufen, deshalb sollte man solche Warnungen mit Vorsicht genießen.

Die Sätze sind **gleichrangig** miteinander verbunden bzw. einander **beigeordnet, nebengeordnet**: daher paßt Regel 2 (entsprechend [§ 71](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/rechtschreibung/6201#par71) der amtlichen Regeln) und nicht Regel 1 (entsprechend [§ 74](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/rechtschreibung/6201#par74) der amtlichen Regeln). Die Tatsache, daß zwischen den Sätzen auch ein Punkt stehen könnte, ist dafür schon hinreichend; ebenso, daß man sie mit *und* verbinden kann; oder die Tatsache, daß jeder von ihnen auch allein, ohne den anderen, stehen könnte.

Die Begriffe *gleichrangig* oder *beigeordnet, nebengeordnet* werden in Rechtschreibregeln normalerweise leider nicht definiert. Was damit gemeint ist: Kein Satz erfüllt eine syntaktische Funktion innerhalb des anderen. Daraus folgen die obengenannten Eigenschaften automatisch: da zwischen den Sätzen keine syntaktische Beziehung besteht, können sie auf beliebige Weise miteinander verbunden werden; sie sind selbständig.

Bei **untergeordneten** Sätzen ist das anders:

> Hans hat gesagt, er bringt Bier mit.

*Er bringt Bier mit* ist ein [Nebensatz](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/terminologie/163), der im übergeordneten Satz die Funktion des Objekts erfüllt. Da *Hans hat gesagt* allein unvollständig ist, ist ein Punkt zwischen diesen Sätzen ausgeschlossen und sie können nicht mit *und* verbunden werden.

Ganz anders dagegen:

> Hans hat zugesagt. Er bringt Bier mit.

*Hans hat zugesagt* ist vollständig und bedarf keines Objekts; *er bringt Bier mit* kann keine syntaktische Funktion innerhalb von *Hans hat zugesagt* ausfüllen. Die Sätze sind unabhängig voneinander und lassen sich daher mit einem Punkt voneinander trennen (aber auch mit einem Komma oder mit *und* verbinden).